# How to set a default schema for a connection in Oracle sql developer 4?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Is there a way to set the default schema for a Database connection in Oracle SQL Developer version 4+?
I see this link for previous versions: http://www.javaforge.com/project/schemasel

...but I can't figure it out for Oracle SQL Developer version 4. If there is a inbuilt functionality in the tool or some login script anyone can suggest will be of great help.

What we are trying to achieve is given below, for each connection we should have a default schema defined.

```
Connection_1 : alter session set current_schema = defaultschema1;
Connection_2 : alter session set current_schema = defaultschema2;
Connection_3 : alter session set current_schema = defaultschema3;
Connection_4 : alter session set current_schema = defaultschema4;
Connection_5 : alter session set current_schema = defaultschema5;
```

Comment: do you have privileges to build a logon trigger ?

Comment: you might be able to do what you want with a login trigger, but the connection tree will be forever tied to the user you're actually logging in as

Comment: Another approach would be to use proxy authentication, which would allow you to use the same real username and password for all the connections, but have them actually connected as someone else. That would show that user's connection tree. But, with all that users privileges - so can create/drop etc. in that schema. So not suitable if you only want to simplify running queries.

Comment: Do you want a PL/SQL Developer solution, since you've tagged it?